# Apache taglib can't find mysql driver in glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, taglib

I'm learning JAVA EE 7.0 by this tutorial:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/connect-db.html

It was going fine until I come to this part:

11. Examine testDataSource.jsp in the browser. You see an HTML table listing data contained in the category and product tables.

The code was successfully generated. but it keeps saying the mysql jdbc driver can't be found:

---

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/affablebean"
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/affablebean"
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.

---

This is what I get in glassfish's log:

Warning:   Context path from ServletContext: /FA-war differs from path from bundle: FA-war
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/affablebean"
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:318)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:201)
    at org.apache.jsp.test.testDataSource_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_query_0(testDataSource_jsp.java:120)
    at org.apache.jsp.test.testDataSource_jsp._jspService(testDataSource_jsp.java:75)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.

---

I tried putting mysql driver to GLASSFISH's lib directory and WEB-INF/lib, neither worked.

But when I tried to ping this data source in glassfish, it can be pinged successfully. So it means actually glassfish should have everything it needs to access mysql.

So what's the problem? I'm doing everything told by the tutorial, except that I'm using glassfish 4.1.1 & netbeans 8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've already defined my web.xml resource reference this way, which is mentioned by other posts, but it doesn't work:<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/affablebean</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It looks like this exception really can mean a lot of totally difference situations.

My situation is: Once I define a resource in glassfish-resources.xml(maybe the name is incorrect), it doesn't really appear in the JDBC entry of glassfish's admin console.

Glassfish considers it an application-scoped resource. It's named :

FA  ----------- java:app/AffableConnPool    JDBC Connection Pools
FA  ----------- java:app/jdbc/affablebean

Look! You see the JNDI is manipulated. I tried java:app/jdbc/affablebean in my sqlquery taglib too, which failed to work too. But I've managed to work around the problem by defining the connection pool manually in glassfish.

Try it if you get the same problem, my friend. Never get stuck on classpath issues, the exception is IRRITATINGLY MISLEADING.